# Linear Search Using Text File C#

Tags: c#, linear-search

So I have a text file which I would like to search through for a number and if it is found then outputs a message number is found and if not then not found.

Currently I have read the text file into a string and asked the user what number they would like to search for. The part I am stuck on is the code for the linear search for a string. I want to look for a string because other files I will use may contain words.

Code So far:

```
    public static void search()   // Search for values
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to search through days");
        int operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (operation == 1)
        {

            String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Day_1.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number to search");
            String myString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have seen some code for a linear search but not sure how to apply it properly to my example. I understand how it works but problem is with getting code in the correct order. Not too good at coding in c#. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Generic Linear Search Code :

```
static int Search(string[] list, string elementSought)
{
bool found = false;
int max = list.Length - 1;
int currentElement = 0;

do
{
    if (list[currentElement] == elementSought)
    {
        found = true;
    }
    else
    {
        currentElement = currentElement + 1;
    }
} while (!(found == true || currentElement > max));

if (found == true)
{
    return currentElement;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
}
```

Update:

```
   public static void search()   // Search for values
    {
  Console.WriteLine("1=Day 2=Depth");
  int operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if (operation == 1)
        {
            String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Day_1.txt");
        }

        else if (operation == 2)
        {
            String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Months_1.txt");
        }


            Console.WriteLine("Enter number to search");
            String myString = Console.ReadLine();
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            var regex = new Regex(myString);
            foreach (string array in myArray)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(array))
                {
                    i++;
                }

                else if (regex.IsMatch(array))
                {
                    j++; 
                }
            }

            if (i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found match! - {1} Appeared {0} time(s)",i,myString);
            }

            else if(j == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Match for {0} in Data", myString);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

How do I change it so that if I choose the second file that it selects that as the one to use as my Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your array of strings in search of a match. Use a regex to check for a match.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number to search");
String myString = Console.ReadLine();

var regex = new Regex(myString);
foreach (string array in myArray)
    if (regex.IsMatch(array))
        Console.WriteLine("Found match!");
```

Comment: Get an error Regex could not be found

Comment: Add your using statement "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;" at the top of your .cs file.

Comment: fixed it nevermind

Comment: How would I make this appear once. Or if it does appear just the number of times rather than writing it out again and again?

Comment: Instead of writing Found match, increment a variable and write the variable after the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, Got it working

Comment: Stuck on this new part. Updated question

Answer (score 1):

you've overcomplicated the task at hand, simply use a for loop for a linear search or using `Linq`:

```
static int Search(string[] list, string elementSought)
{
    return list.ToList().FindIndex(s => s == elementSought);
}
```

Comment: And how would you know in which line you found it?... :-)

Comment: @Juan edited the answer to accommodate that.

Comment: @Juan OP did not mention that. Only mentioned linear search of array. Nothing about line #s.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras: Yes, it did not mention that. However, it is a search and if you look at the original algorithm, it returns the line number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return -1 if the item is not found int the array, otherwise the index of its first occurrence.

**Example (console app)**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] list = {"xxx", "yyy", "aaa", "bbb"};
        var found = Search(list, "gggg");
    }

    static bool Search(string[] list, string elementSought)
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(list, elementSought);

        var found = index != -1;

        return found;
    }
```